# Integration test of microservice with Feign, OAuth2 and Spock

Tags: java, integration-testing, spring-security-oauth2, spock, feign

I am currently developing microservice that is registering users in system. I wanted to create some integration tests of my controller but I've encountered some problem with OAuth2 and Feign. The thing is that my controller method (which I want to test) has some service call and inside that service there is also a call to feign client interface which points to another microservice. But in this moment when feign is called, I am getting access denied through OAuth2. Is there any way to completely stub/mock this method so that when it is trying to call method from feign interface it returns some mocked data?

Here is my controller method:

```
    @PostMapping
    public UserDto register(@Valid @RequestBody AccountRegisterRequest request) {
        return accountService.register(accountRegisterRequestConverter.convertTo(request));
    }
```

Here is my account service method `register`:

```
    public UserDto register(Account account) {
        UserDto createdUser = authServiceFeignClient.createUser(account.getUserRegistrationDto());
        if (nonNull(createdUser)) {
            account.setUserId(Long.parseLong(createdUser.getId()));
            Account savedAccount = repository.save(account);
            System.out.println("Account saved: " + savedAccount.getNickname());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Account saving error! User was not created.");
        }
        return createdUser;
    }
```

And also `authServiceFeignClient`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "auth-service", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
public interface AuthServiceFeignApi {

    @PostMapping(value = "/uaa/user")
    UserDto createUser(@RequestBody UserRegistrationDto user);
}
```

And here are is my test configuration and test itself written in Spock:

```
class AccountIntegrationSpec extends MicroserviceIntegrationSetup implements AccountFixture {

    @Autowired
    AccountController accountController

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService

    @Autowired
    AccountValidator accountValidator

    def setup() {
        stubForCreatingDefaultUser()
    }

    def 'should create user and receive result'() {
        given:
        def createAccountRequest = createAccountRegisterRequest()

        when:
        def result = accountController.register(createAccountRequest)

        then:
        result.username == "Username"
        result.id == "1"

    }
}
```

```
@CompileStatic
@SpringBootTest(classes = AccountServiceApplication.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(Stubs)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
abstract class MicroserviceIntegrationSetup extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseCleaner databaseCleaner

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authFeignApi")
    AuthServiceFeignApi authServiceFeignApi

    @Before
    def cleanDatabase() {
        databaseCleaner.deleteAll()
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Stubs {
        DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

        @Bean(name = "authFeignApi")
        AuthServiceFeignApi authServiceFeignApi() {
            factory.Mock(AuthServiceFeignApi)
        }
    }

    def stubForCreatingUser(UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto) {
        authServiceFeignApi.createUser(userRegistrationDto) >> new UserDto("1", userRegistrationDto.username)
    }

    def stubForCreatingDefaultUser() {
        authServiceFeignApi.createUser(_ as UserRegistrationDto) >> new UserDto("1", "Username")
    }

}
```

To summarize, I would like that this test would pass and is completely ignoring oauth2 and also `authServiceFeignClient` is properly stubbed/mocked and is returning data that are provided in `stubForCreatingDefaultUser` method.
Any help is appreciated, maybe this approach is pointless, then some other suggestion are also welcomed.

Comment: You will probably be looking for `@SpringBean AuthServiceFeignApi feign = Mock()`. (And note that it's idiomatic to put expected values first, then actual values.)

Comment: Should I use it in place of `@Autowired` bean or in place of `@Bean(name = "authFeignApi")` in `@TestConfiguration`?

Comment: In place of the `@TestConfiguration`. (Your configuration approach _will_ work, but it's more work than `@SpringBean`, and you still need to provide access to the mock API to your test class.)

Comment: Well, that worked just fine, thank you very much. Wish I knew about this `@SpringBean` annotation earlier.

Comment: I think it was only added in Spock 1.2, so documentation might not have info on it yet.